# About Redux-thunk, if a handler dispatches a function to be called, why not call it directly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

As I understand [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), it can be

```
<button onClick={fn1}>Click Me</button>
```

and in `fn1`, it dispatches not an action object, but dispatches a function `fn2`, so that when the `redux-thunk` middleware calls it ( meaning `fn2`), invoke a `fetch` or Ajax call, and let the `then` fulfillment handler or the callback of Ajax dispatch an action object, like

```
{ type: "DATA_RECEIVED", data: data }
```

but why doesn't `fn1` directly call `fn2` to do the task, but let the middleware call it instead?

Comment: Because then `fn2` would be fired immediately, instead of after the `fetch` is done, or am I missunderstanding your question?

Comment: @zero298 the thing is you do want `fn2` to fire immediately. Such as: user clicks a button to fetch something, you do want the function that does the `fetch` or Ajax to fire immediately. I think with `redux-thunk`, if you dispatch a function, it *is* fired immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux Thunk is a ***very*** thin middleware (like 14 lines thin) that introduces the convention that Redux should know how to deal with asynchronous processes for you.

You said

> the thing is you do want fn2 to fire immediately. Such as: user clicks
>   a button to fetch something, you do want the function that does the
>   fetch or Ajax to fire immediately. I think with redux-thunk, if you
>   dispatch a function, it is fired immediately

You're right, you **do** want it to fire immediately, but do you want to be the one that manually wires up calling the function and passing the dispatch or do you want Redux Thunk to do it for you?

No matter what, Redux is going to need to dispatch an action at some later time.  Redux Thunk does the "later" for you.

Consider these differences:

```js
const store = {
  dispatch() {
    console.log("Dispatch");
  }
};

// Action creator that retuns an action
const inc = () => ({
  type: "INCREMENT"
});

// Impure action creator that you shouldn't use
const badAsyncInc = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: "INCREMENT"
    });
  }, 1000);
};

// Action creator that returns a function that takes dispatch as arg
const aInc = () => dis => setTimeout(() => dis({
  type: "INCREMENT"
}), 1000);

/*
 * The following will do everything including waiting to dispatch
 * and dispatching to the store.  That's good, but not good for
 * when we want to use a different store.
 */
badAsyncInc()();

/*
 * The following is the "manual" way of wiring up the delayed
 * dispatch that you have to do without Redux Thunk.
 */
aInc()(store.dispatch);

/*
 * With Redux Thunk, this will call the "fn2" immediately but also
 * pass the dispatch function to "fn2" for you so that you don't 
 * have to wire that up yourself.
 */
store.dispatch(aInc);
```

In this instance, you could just call `badAsyncInc` and be done since it will call `store.dispatch` for you.  But what if you have multiple stores?  What if you want to use a testing harness' store?  What if you want to mock the store completely?  Your `badAsyncInc` is now coupled with the store which is bad for action creators.

Alternatively, you can just call `aInc` yourself and pass it a dispatch function.  However, why do that when all your other action creators are probably being written as `store.dispatch(actionCreator())`.  Redux Thunk helps you keep that pattern, even with async actions.

Redux Thunk tries to help you write action creators that are loosely coupled and testable.

Comment: Should it be `aInc()(store.dispatch);` instead?

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie Yes, I think you're right.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

> in fn1, it dispatches not an action object, but dispatches a function fn2

The motivation behind dispatching a function is that the function includes a dispatch argument (which Redux Thunk provides) for you to use.

Here is an example of how powerful making dispatch available can be:

```
const action = (url) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        dispatch(success(response));
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(failure(error));
    }
}
```

Dispatch enables you to dispatch a success or failure action for your reducers to handle.

More details: 
https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/#async-action-creators

> if a handler dispatches a function to be called, why not call it directly?

If it were called immediately, you couldn't cleanly do the above: dispatching subsequent actions after **resolving** a fetch or any asynchronous call.